# writing dll , c# (concept)

Tags: c#

I  have a basic question.

1-
I want to use **Science.dll** provided at

http://www.sciencecode.com/

I want to add some new functions in some *XXX.cs* files and also some new *YYY.cs* files. Then I want to make dll of them again (**Science.dll** with changes) and use it. How it can be done.

Should I make a new project and add all more than 100 files (already given on website) in that project and some my new *YYY.cs* files and then what should be next step???

2-
I wanna ask about best way to put many different functions in one 'utilities.cs' file. Say I have different static functions *printmatrix, read_text_file,* etc. What should I do, so that I directly use them in main program.  What should be the way in c#.In c++ I wrote header file and cpp file named utilities and then I used these functions.

Any good idea.

Comment: They are also hosting it on http://sc.codeplex.com/, you can get source code from there :) may it helps ! thnq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify an existing assembly unless you have the source code of it. What you could do is create a new class library project in Visual Studio, add Science.dll as a reference and then add your own functions which could use functions in the referenced assembly. When you compile your project it will produce another assembly.

Comment: I want to write some functions (utilities). What should be the way in c#.In c++ I wrote header file and cpp file named utilities and then I used these functions

Comment: @shahbaba, in order to use this library you could reference it in any type of .NET project. Could be console application, winforms application, ASP.NET application, ... You could also reference it in a class library project and add your own functions.

Comment: I wanna ask about best way to put many different functions in one 'utilities.cs' file. Say  have different static functions printmatrix, read_text_file, etc. What should I do, so that I directly use them in main program.

Comment: @shahbaba, assuming your functions are inside a static class called `Utilities`, in your main program you will call them like this: `Utilities.printmatrix();`.

Answer (score 1):

First you make a new project taht has reference on the science.dll.in Visual studio
You can inheritance its class and add yours functionality.
You can use partial class that has the same name as in the science.dll. and add your functionality
eg:
science.dll

```
public class Calc
{
   public Int32 Add(Int32 a, Int32 b){..implementation...}
}
```

yourproject.dll

```
public partial class Calc
{
   public Int32 Minus(Int32 a, Int32 b) {..implementation..}
}
```

You can use extension method with your functionality. This is depend on your implementation.
For detail implementation you can see on MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library for both C# and VB.NET on both syntak

In the caller project, make sure add reference both science.dll and yourproject.dll.